# Get cities by state and country Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I try to use Google Places API for this goal, and I know how to get cities by country. But I need add option for search by country and state of USA. May be I should use some another API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it is not supported in Places API.

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker to add this functionality:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote.

A workaround might be using bounds for each state and option strictBounds: true to restrict result to certain area.